# How to solve Taskhash mismatch and metadata is not deterministic in Yocto project build?

Tags: metadata, yocto, bitbake, mismatch

I am facing "Taskhash mismatch" & "The metadata is not deterministic and this needs to be fixed" error in Yocto project build. This issue arises without any obvious reasons. With a perfectly good source code repo, the build is success sometime, while it fails some time. There is no change in source code/recipe or any other build parameters.

Error log:

```
ERROR: When reparsing /home/user/my_project/yocto/sub_project-yocto/meta-subproject/meta-base/recipes-core/sub_project-rootfs-base/sub_project-rootfs-base.bb:do_populate_lic, the basehash value changed from e0bfa2ad64f24d189d23f9d84918c74a7253e0d7e9c7fea4e3346cbc473d43da to c108c533ec82c43aa15730e4ca9c9838f87133e63417f40af0de8ca8cb43f51a. The metadata is not deterministic and this needs to be fixed.
ERROR: The following commands may help:
ERROR: $ bitbake sub_project-rootfs-base -cdo_populate_lic -Snone
ERROR: Then:
ERROR: $ bitbake sub_project-rootfs-base -cdo_populate_lic -Sprintdiff

ERROR: sub_project-rootfs-base-1.0+gitAUTOINC+db239d9f5b-r2 do_package_qa: Taskhash mismatch 87d8616452c2be01481a9034e9147f0270a57a3f64f85cde65076863b8123c7c versus 9a7fd3b27e62140001d77ab75dbc2026dac8e6c8ca93a487b1857a76f2b6b2yy for /home/user/my_project/yocto/sub_project-yocto/meta-subproject/meta-base/recipes-core/sub_project-rootfs-base/sub_project-rootfs-base.bb:do_package_qa
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch 87d8616452c2be01481a9034e9147f0270a57a3f64f85cde65076863b8123c7c versus 9a7fd3b27e62140001d77ab75dbc2026dac8e6c8ca93a487b1857a76f2b6b2yy for /home/user/my_project/yocto/sub_project-yocto/meta-subproject/meta-base/recipes-core/sub_project-rootfs-base/sub_project-rootfs-base.bb:do_package_qa
ERROR: sub_project-rootfs-base-1.0+gitAUTOINC+db239d9f5b-r2 do_package_write_rpm: Taskhash mismatch 9a7fd3b27e62140001d77ab75dbc2026dac88qc8ca93a487b1857a76f2b6b2yy versus 9a7fd3b27e6217l0001d77ab75dbc2026dac8e6c8ca93a487b1857a76f2b6b2yy for /home/user/my_project/yocto/sub_project-yocto/meta-subproject/meta-base/recipes-core/sub_project-rootfs-base/sub_project-rootfs-base.bb:do_package_write_rpm
ERROR: Taskhash mismatch 9a7fd3b27e62140001d77ab75dbc2026dac88qc8ca93a487b1857a76f2b6b2yy versus 9a7fd3b27e6217l0001d77ab75dbc2026dac8e6c8ca93a487b1857a76f2b6b2yy for /home/user/my_project/yocto/sub_project-yocto/meta-subproject/meta-base/recipes-core/sub_project-rootfs-base/sub_project-rootfs-base.bb:do_package_write_rpm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by doing two of the following action.

1. Clean the recipe which throws error during build using following command

   - bitbake -c cleansstate sub_project-rootfs-base
2. Update the bb file timestamp by doing empty write or by touching file.

   - Open the bb file using your editor - vim /home/user/my_project/yocto/sub_project-yocto/meta-subproject/meta-base/recipes-core/sub_project-rootfs-base/sub_project-rootfs-base.bb
   - Write the file by clicking save button or in vim writing ":w" command
   - Close the file using "x" button or ":q" command.

Rebuild the project as usual.

Edit : In case there are multiple bitbake recipes showing this error, you can touch all bb files and build again. Go into your yocto folder and run following command. This will take some to touch all file and significantly higher time to rebuild the project.

```
find . -type f -name "*.bb" -exec touch {} +
```